# "Closed" is to "Reopened" as "On Hold" is to (what)?

Tags: discussion, on-hold, terminology

Now that questions are first "On Hold" instead of "Closed", what is the best phrase to use when telling users the requirements to "Reopen" their question?

Although behind the scenes everything is still called "close" and "reopen", the user would be confused if we said their question can be "reopened". Do we call it "Releasing" a question or is "Reopen" still the correct term?

Comment: Dropped. Wait...

Comment: "No holds barred"?

Comment: Freed from the chains of their oppressors?

Comment: Reopened 2: Electric Boogaloo

Comment: Re-animated ...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any such phrase, at least not something that will be clear enough as to not have the OP ask "What do you mean?" then you will have to explain anyway.

So suppose you have advice for the OP something like this should pass your message just fine:

> Your question is now on hold because [this and that] so it can't get new answers. Please [do this and that] so that you can receive answers again

(the auto generated banner says this already, so add such comment only if you have concrete advice)

Answer (score 2):

"Have the hold removed" or "remove the hold."

Answer (score 2):

"Off Hold"

You put a question on hold, and then you take it off hold.